# Developing an ISAPI filter

Tags: c#, c++, iis, isapi

I want to develop an ISAPI filter which shall read the headers of an URL, this shall talk to an ASP .NET application . Can this be achieved in C# , or do I need to develop this in C++ , and create a CLI/C++ DLL so that the ASP .NET application can communicate with the C++ dll .

Comment: IIS6 or IIS7? What you say "talk to an ASP.NET application" what do you intend to do?

Comment: Both IIS and IIS 7 should be supported . The extracted data by the ISAPI fileter shall be sent to the ASP .NET application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .Net you use HTTPModule and HTTPHandlers to accomplish what ISAPI gave you before.

Here is a decent MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Comment: I know of them . Do they give the same granularity as ISAPI provides.

Comment: They give pretty much the same functionality of ISAPI.  Some drawbacks include slower execution (of course managed code will be slower than unmanaged, but without all the other headaches of unmanaged code) and the inability for classic ASP applications to interact with your module.  If you need to integrate classic ASP with .Net then your only true option is to go ISAPI.  If you are going full .Net then it's best to use the HTTPModules and HTTPHandlers.