# How to create an ISAPI Filter DLL in vb.net/c# or vbscript

Tags: c#, dll, asp-classic, vbscript, isapi

I have researched a lot on internet about creating one but only ones I found were to create in c++.
Is there a way to create one in c# or vb.net?
can anyone please provide links to tutorials 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing an ISAPI filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909340/developing-an-isapi-filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question - You have to create ISAPI DLLS in c++, there is no tother way to do it

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: **No**, you cannot create an ISAPI in C# or VB.NET.  Building an ISAPI  requires the use of unmanaged code - C or C++.

You can create filter-like function in .NET languages, [starting with IIS7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757017.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

better read the reaction instead of my mis-informed answer

c# is not the choice, isapi.dll should be com aware that's a pain in c#
vb.net exactly the same, that's why the examples are in c++
it 'should' be possible in c# with regasm but really... don't go there, you'll fall short off support, examples etc etc etc...

if you tell me a bit more, maybe there are alternatives to an isapi (there are always alternatives even cool ones you'll never imagine)....

Comment: -1 The ISAPI has nothing to do with COM.  If it were simply a matter of implementing a COM object thats fairly straight forward in C#.  However IIS expects an ISAPI filter to export specific standard DLL entry points, this is the reason that a minimum C++ is needed.  Of course one can just delegate into managed code from there so the C++ needn't do a lot.